# Como renderizar contenido html guardado en base de datos en vue

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor

Espero se encuentren bien, tengo una duda sobre como renderizar un texto que fue guardado en mi base de datos a traves de ckeditor, en mi base de datos luce literalmente asi:

```
<h2><i><strong>Post de prueba :)</strong></i></h2><figure class="table"><table><tbody><tr><td>Probando 1</td><td>Probando 2</td></tr></tbody></table></figure><figure class="image"><img src="http://larablog.test/images_post/1619471816.jpg"></figure><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

estoy obteniendo este dato y mas desde una rest api mediante fetch, y estoy obteniendo los datos atraves de un v-for:

```
<div class="card mt-3"  v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.title">
        <img v-bind:src="post.image.image" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{post.content}}</p>
          <button href="#" class="btn btn-primary" @click="postClick(post)">Ver Resumen</button>
          <router-link class="btn btn-success" :to="{name:'detail', params:{id: post.id}}">Ver Detalle</router-link>
        </div>
</div>
```

el post.content es lo que contiene el texto guardado desde un ckeditor y quiero que se apliquen las etiquetas y las clases, estoy renderizandolo en vue.

Comment: Y como lo estas mostrando en vue?

Comment: podrías intentar con la propiedad [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: @gbianchi pues estoy trayendo datos json desde una consulta fetch y estoy iterando con un v-for, el contenido que contiene html lo estoy mostrando asi: <p class="card-text">{{post.content}}</p>. Me lo muestra pero lo muestra textual, no renderiza los tags ni las clases.

Comment: fijate que necesitas v-html

Comment: @Eduardo no se manipula el dom en vue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a @gbianchi encontré la solución, solo tuve que agregar el v-html, el codigo quedo asi:

```
<div class="card mt-3"  v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.title">
        <img v-bind:src="post.image.image" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h5>

          <!-- para leer el contenido como html y no texto plano  -->
          <p class="card-text" v-html="post.content"></p>

          <button href="#" class="btn btn-primary" @click="postClick(post)">Ver Resumen</button>
          <router-link class="btn btn-success" :to="{name:'detail', params:{id: post.id}}">Ver Detalle</router-link>
        </div>
</div>
```

Pueden encontrar esto en la documentación: https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#HTML-Puro